# Blender 3D models give incorrect dimensions

Tags: export, 3d-printing, dimensions

When I model something in blender to be 3d-printed, I **always** get wrong dimensions in stl file, even though I've set `scene units` to metric, `scale` to 1 and in blender viewport, it shows the correct dimmensions.
[image]

---

But when I convert and export the model to an stl file, dimensions get converted to millimeters, no matter the settings or model dimensions in blender.
[image]

---

For exporting blender model to stl files, I am using a blender addon named '3D Print Toolbox'. At first, i thought I need to change some setting in the addon, but couldn't find anything to play around with.

[image]

---

My real problem/question is - Is there something that I am missing or doing wrong?

Perhaps some setting or step that I am overlooking before exporting.

PS: As a workaround, each time, I have to scale up the exported stl file model.

Comment: I don't use tools like this, but do you apply the scale of the object after scaling or scale in edit mode? Judging by how blender works, this might be necessary.

Comment: I've tried both the methods of scaling, but the result's the same.